# Which circuit breaker will blow first?

Tags: circuit-protection

Assume that Each circuit breaker is identical.

Each breaker trips at 15 amps on a 120V circuit.

One circuit breaker is located back at the circuit box with 50 feet of wire to the outlet.

The other circuit breaker is located at the outlet with 5 feet of wire to a high load application which draws more than 15 amps.

**Which circuit breaker has a higher chance of blowing?**

I would imagine the one at the box because more current may exist due to the resistance in the 50 feet of wire.

Comment: The fastest one. KCL says they all have the same amount of current going through them.

Comment: The one that is hardest to replace, according to Murphy's law.

Comment: You can reuse either https://bytesizedpieces.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/blown_fuse_earrings.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the breakers are absolutely identical, then they will both trip at the same instant.

The current flowing through them both will be the exact same amount of current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqez6k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With no branches in the circuit, just a simple ring, the current at all points will be the same - simple KCL.  AM1 == AM2.

Answer (score 5):

The warmer one will trip first in an overload (not short circuit) situation with identical breakers and identical current.

Comment: If one is warmer then they're not identical.

Comment: @Majenko The operating conditions are not the same, but the breakers themselves can still be identical (in other words, you could swap the two breakers and the results would be exactly the same). Other things that could affect the trip point are the air pressure (the one in a vacuum will trip first, for sure), the humidity, the tightness of the screws holding the wire (and probably a few others I've not thought of).

Comment: But those environmental factors affect the circuit breaker, and that external effect renders them not identical.  If you have two coke cans, and stamp on one of them, an external environmental factor has changed the properties of the coke can. They are no longer the same.

Comment: I think the fact you can swap the breakers at any time and get the identical results is incontrovertible evidence. ;-) In your thought experiment, you've irreversibly changed the Coke(tm) can so it's no longer identical from that point forward. I specifically avoided saying that the more worn breaker would trip first (though it's generally true) since those two breakers would not be identical.

Comment: Ok, so not a coke can then - a balloon. You fill one with helium but not the other. The two are now different. You let the helium out of that one, then fill the other. You have now swapped the balloons. By swapping the breakers you are placing them in each other's environments, and those environments then affect them in the same way, giving you the same results. They can only be identical if they are in identical environments. Increased heat induces extra energy into the atoms which makes them behave differently. At the different energy levels the atoms are no longer identical.

Comment: I'm on Spehro's side here. "Identical" devices does not imply identical operating environments.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the real-life fact that circuit breakers vary widely in their cut-off current: both will break at the same time, because they get equal current. The two breakers and the load are in series, so the current simply has to be equal. There might be some difference in the (ground-referenced) potential at the terminals of both breakers, but they won't notice.

Answer (score 0):

With both Ckt breakers at the same ambient temperature the Ckt breaker closest to the source of the fault will trip. 35 years of experience.